# While function how do I use both & and |

Tags: while-loop, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am a total noob so when I explain simple stuff, it's not because I'm retarded, it's just that I want to know if I think wrong or right.

I have 2 variables at first, `x1` and `y1`. I put them in a `while ()` like this

```
while ( y1<0 || y1>500 || x1<0 || x1>500)
```

I read this as "when one of these "things" are true, it will do the while function.

So for example if `y1=601`, `y1>500` is true, the other 3 are false but it goes into the function since only 1 need to be true.

Now here's where I get problem, I want to add a third variable called `z`. I add it like this:

```
while(y1<0 || y1>500 || x1<0 || x1>500 && z>51)
```

What I want this to do is run the while function ONLY if `z>51` is true together with at least 1 more function. Or if thats not possible, I want it to run ONLY if `z>51` is true. My code is wrong because right now it just continues on forever even if `z>51` is false.

Comment: Is this C?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: As others have said, merely group together what you want in parenthesis, whether that is grouping the "and" or the "or"s.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly your question, you want:

```
while((y1<0 || y1>500 || x1<0 || x1>500) && z>51)
```

In boolean logic, **and** (also noted **^** or **.**) has a higher priority than **or** (also noted **v** or **+**).

Which means that:

`y1<0 || y1>500 || x1<0 || x1>500 && z>51`

is equivalent to

`y1<0 || y1>500 || x1<0 || (x1>500 && z>51)`

Therefore, you need parenthesis if that's not what you want, exactly like the parenthesis you add when you use `+` and `*` in maths.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 checks are separate.

You can't simply write `y1<0 || 50051`
You have to write `(y1<0 || y1>50051)`

`50051` always evaluates to `true` hence I assume it would run forever

for your last request

```
while(z1>51 && y1 >0)
```

Comment: something went wrong when i copy pasted my code.. dunno why but i had to manually write it and it shows correctly now.

Comment: in some programming languages 50051 would not typecheck as it is not strictly a boolean (which would be either true or false)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could check the value of z first and keep the loop unchanged.

```
if (z > 51) {
  while ( [...])
  [...]
}
```

This is slightly different to Maxime's solution as it assumes that the value of `z` does not matter once you enter the loop. If you on the other hand want to update `z` and use it as condition to exit the loop then keep it in the `while` condition.

Comment: what if `z` changes in the while?